# Is there any compact relay (or any high current) chip for Raspberry PI?

Tags: gpio, relay

I am fascinated how L293D makes it easy to control a DC motor.

I wonder if there is any similar popular chip that controls a set of relays, so I don't have to use a bunch of transistors?

PS. I am aware that I can buy a relay pack. With this post, I like to learn if there is any relay controller chip.

Update:
ULN2803A suggested by @Ghanima is the answer. This chip can be very useful for Raspberry PI or Arduino projects. Not sure why this question is moved here?
I am  updating the title and body of the question and including keywords "Raspberry PI", to help others when they search for this info.

Comment: Usually, though not always, the correct answer is "stop using relays".

Comment: @NickJohnson, then what should I use instead of a relay?

Comment: Mosfet + optoinsulator would be one option. It depends on what exactly you're intending to do.  Some cases might be accomplished even with a transistor...

Comment: Relays are by far the simplest and most isolated way to switch mains power from a low voltage system.

Comment: @pjc50 Who said anything about switching mains power?

Comment: @AllanXu Depends on your application. Often people use relays because they're easy to reason about, when a simple MOSFET transistor would be simpler, cheaper, and more reliable.

Comment: @NickJohnson I did - as an example of a common application where "stop using relays" doesn't make sense. Of course neither of us know what OP's actual application is..

Comment: @pjc50 I never claimed relays were always a bad idea or doubted the existence of applications for which relays are the best tool. In fact, I said "usually though not always".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest a low-side transistor array, such as the ULN2803A "Darlington Transistor Arrays" to get eight channels per package. With 500 mA per channel it is perfectly suited to directly drive small relays. Note that this is the absolute maximum rating. If using all channels simultaneously the total substrate-terminal current of 2.5 A is limiting here. So a reasonable maximum is 300 mA per channel. Be advised that at this current the collector-emitter saturation voltage leads to worst case power dissipation of 3.8 W.

Somewhere burried deep in the data sheet it is suggested that it works with 3.3 V logic levels as provided by the Raspberries GPIO pins.

Comment: ULN2803 FTW - 50v, 500mA, 8 channels, flyback protected, sensible pinout

Comment: Thank you @Ghanima. How can I find this type of useful chips, besides asking questions here?

Comment: I happen to remembered this part remotely from using it extensively in the past. I also have this page for a short list of standard components http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Standardbauelemente but it is in German... However I am pretty sure there'll be something like that around in English too!

Comment: regarding that 500mA - thats the absolute maximum combined rating. 
Per channel it's max 300mA in-spec, and i thinks it's a combined over-all-channels 500mA maximum.

Comment: www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf reads "collector-current rating of each Darlington pair is 500 mA" It is however the value listed too in the "absolute maximum ratings". There it also reads "Total substrate-terminal current –2.5 A". So I take it that 300 mA per channel with all channels used simultaneously is within spec. CE saturation voltage however would in this case indicate a hefty 3 W thermal dissipation. So you're right to advise not to blow 500 mA at every channel.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different alternative is to use a high power Shift Register such as the [TPIC6B595](https://www.adafruit.com/products/457). This chip can sink 150mA continuous per output, and I have used them in the past to switch small relays with no issues.

The shift register is slightly more complicated to control/write code for, but has the advantage of only needing 3 GPIO pins to control a theoretically limitless number of outputs/relays, by daisy chaining them together (and still only needing 3 GPIO pins). So if you're running low on RPi/Arduino pins, this may be an alternative.

The logic input can be any voltage between 0.3V-7V, and the power supply to the chip, \$V_{CC}\$, is recommended to be between 4.5V-5.5V. All voltage levels which are available on the RPi.